# Splitting date and time then put into other column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, datetime

I'm working a small date time project. From my CSV file I have 4 columns, called Name, Employee ID, Data/Time, Status and in my Database columns are name, empID, date, timeIn, timeOut, Status.

Picture of my csv file: (Picture A)

[image]

And here is what I want to save in my database: (Picture B)

[image]

Example input CSV string:

```
Name,"Empoyee ID",Date/Time,Status
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,"05/03/2019 1:01:03 PM",C/Out
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,"05/04/2019 2:01:03 PM",C/In
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,"05/04/2019 3:01:03 PM",C/Out
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,"05/06/2019 4:01:03 PM",C/In
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,"05/06/2019 5:01:03 PM",C/Out
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,"05/07/2019 6:01:03 PM",C/In
```

How can I get started on this problem?

### Edit

I want to thanks @jimmix for giving me some idea to get started.

Here is the real scenario:

From my CSV file, I have the data you can found at (Picture A), then I will upload using my upload() function in into my MySQL database with the table name "tbldumpbio",

See the table structure below:

[image]

From my table tbldumpbio data, I have a function called processTimesheet()

Here's the code:

```
public function processTimesheet(){
        $this->load->model('dbquery');          

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbldumpbio");

            foreach ($query->result() as $row){

            $dateTimeExplArr = explode(' ', $row->datetimex);

            $dateStr = $dateTimeExplArr[0];
            $timeStr = $dateTimeExplArr[1];

            if($row->status='C/Out' and !isset($timeStr) || empty($timeStr) ){
                $timeStrOut ='';
            } else {
                $timeStrOut = $dateTimeExplArr[1];
            }

            if($row->status='C/In' and !isset($timeStr) || empty($timeStr) ){
                $timeStrIn ='';     
            } else {
                $timeStrIn = $dateTimeExplArr[1];   
            }

            $data = array(
                'ID' => '',
                'companyAccessID' => '',
                'name' => $row->name,
                'empCompID' => $row->empid,
                'date' => $dateStr,
                'timeIn' => $timeStrIn,
                'timeOut' => $timeStrOut,
                'status' => '',
                'inputType' => ''       
            );              
            $this->dbquery->modInsertval('tblempbioupload',$data);


            }
    }
```

This function will add a another data into tblempbioupload. But here are the results that I'm getting with:

Please see the below data:

[image]

The problem is:

- the date should not be duplicated
- Time In data should be added if the status is 'C/In'
- Time Out data should be added if the status is 'C/Out'

The expected result should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: im guessing there's some code generating this csv, unless you use dark magic and it just magically appears

Comment: Please post the relevant method in your DarkMagic class.

Comment: We don't provide "dirty headstarts" here.  We provide clear, professional, educational, complete answers to questions that show research and coding effort.  Right now your question is Unclear and Too Broad and is likely to attract more downvotes.  There are probably thousands of StackOverflow pages that will give you a "headstart".  You are asking multiple questions here.  "How to parse a csv file" "How to explode a date" "How to conditionally write data to an array column" "How to query a database table"

Comment: thanks for the info, but as I said Im just only want to ask some idea or logic and not the whole code. Btw, thanks.

Comment: @zeus2026 Please post next time question that has some **example code** and/or **input** and **expected output** data so people answering your question have something to work with because there are plenty of people answering with working solution rather than just giving an idea how to approach a problem but they need the data. For posting input/output data use **code** formatting button.

Comment: I've edit my question, Please see my edit quiestion.. I'm sorry again for not clearing up my question. This will not be happening again.. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Not the shortest one but working:

```
<?php

$csvMultilineStr =
'Name,"Empoyee ID",Date/Time,Status
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,"05/03/2019 1:01:03 PM",C/Out
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,"05/04/2019 2:01:03 PM",C/In
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,"05/04/2019 3:01:03 PM",C/Out
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,"05/06/2019 4:01:03 PM",C/In
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,"05/06/2019 5:01:03 PM",C/Out
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,"05/07/2019 6:01:03 PM",C/In';

//read CSV as every line = 1 array item
$csvArr = explode("\n", $csvMultilineStr);

//get header line as array of column names
//and remove that line from $csvArr
$headerArr = str_getcsv(array_shift($csvArr));

$emplIdKeyStr = "Empoyee ID";
$resultArr = [];

/**
 * Create array of arrays
 * that each array inside an array
 * is under key of emploeeId and
 * represents one CSV row
 * 
 * [
 *   901 => [
 *              0 => [
 *                      'Name' => value
 *                      'Empoyee ID' => value2
 *                      ...
 *                  ],
 *             1 => [
 *                      'Name' => value
 *                      'Empoyee ID' => value2
 *                      ...
 *                  ]
 *          ]
 * ]
 * 
 */
foreach($csvArr as $csvLineStr) {
    $csvEntryArr = str_getcsv($csvLineStr);
    $csvLineArr = array_combine($headerArr, $csvEntryArr);
    $emplIdInt = $csvLineArr[$emplIdKeyStr];
    $resultArr[$emplIdInt][] = $csvLineArr;
}

var_export($resultArr);

/**
 * Create array of arrays
 * as above but with key => value
 * structure
 * 
 * [
 *  901 => [
 *              '05/03/2019' => [
 *                                  'C/In' => ...
 *                                  'C/Out' => ...
 *                                  'name' => ...
 *                              ]
 *          ]
 * ]
 * 
 */
$resultTimeIoArr = [];
$timeInOutColSwStr = 'Status';
$dateTimeColStr = 'Date/Time';
foreach($resultArr as $emplIdInt => $emplEntyArr) {

    foreach($emplEntyArr as $emplSingleEntryArr) {
        $dateTimeStr = $emplSingleEntryArr[$dateTimeColStr];

        $dateTimeExplArr = explode(' ', $dateTimeStr);
        $dateStr = $dateTimeExplArr[0];
        $timeStr = $dateTimeExplArr[1];

        $resultTimeIoArr[$emplIdInt][$dateStr][$emplSingleEntryArr[$timeInOutColSwStr]] = $timeStr;
        $resultTimeIoArr[$emplIdInt][$dateStr]['name'] = '"' . $emplSingleEntryArr['Name'] . '"';
    }
}

/**
 * get sorted array by EmplId, Date, C/In or C/Out
 * as an arry similar to first one CsvArr
 */
$resultCsvArr = [];
$resultCsvLineArr = [];
foreach($resultTimeIoArr as $emplIdInt => $singleEmplArr) {

    foreach($singleEmplArr as $dateStr => $signleIoArr) {

        $resultCsvLineArr['Name'] = $signleIoArr['name'];
        $resultCsvLineArr['EmpID'] = $emplIdInt;
        $resultCsvLineArr['Date'] = $dateStr;

        if(!isset($signleIoArr['C/In']) || empty($signleIoArr['C/In'])) {
            $timeIn = '';
        } else {
            $timeIn = $signleIoArr['C/In'];
        }

        if(!isset($signleIoArr['C/Out']) || empty($signleIoArr['C/Out'])) {
            $timeOut = '';
        } else {
            $timeOut = $signleIoArr['C/Out'];
        }

        $resultCsvLineArr['timeIn'] = $timeIn;
        $resultCsvLineArr['timeOut'] = $timeOut;
        $resultCsvArr[] = $resultCsvLineArr;
    }
}

echo "--- Array Result ---\n";
var_export($resultCsvArr);

//get header line as arry of column names 
//from the keys of the first array
$head = array_keys($resultCsvArr[0]);

//put arr of header as 1st sting to csv string
$csvStr = implode(',',$head) . "\n";

//put all the rest in result sting
foreach($resultCsvArr as $resultEntryArr) {
    $csvStr .= implode(',',$resultEntryArr) . "\n";
}

// file_put_contents('path-to-file', $csvStr);

echo "\n\n --- CSV Result ---\n";
print_r($csvStr);
```

gives output:

> --- Array Result ---

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Name' => '"Soriano, Jhoniel"',
    'EmpID' => 901,
    'Date' => '05/03/2019',
    'timeIn' => '',
    'timeOut' => '1:01:03',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Name' => '"Soriano, Jhoniel"',
    'EmpID' => 901,
    'Date' => '05/04/2019',
    'timeIn' => '2:01:03',
    'timeOut' => '3:01:03',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Name' => '"Soriano, Jhoniel"',
    'EmpID' => 901,
    'Date' => '05/06/2019',
    'timeIn' => '4:01:03',
    'timeOut' => '5:01:03',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'Name' => '"Soriano, Jhoniel"',
    'EmpID' => 901,
    'Date' => '05/07/2019',
    'timeIn' => '6:01:03',
    'timeOut' => '',
  ),
)
```

> --- CSV Result ---

```
Name,EmpID,Date,timeIn,timeOut
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,05/03/2019,,1:01:03
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,05/04/2019,2:01:03,3:01:03
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,05/06/2019,4:01:03,5:01:03
"Soriano, Jhoniel",901,05/07/2019,6:01:03,
```

use:

```
file_put_contents('path-to-file', $csvStr);
```

at the end to save the csv to file.

Comment: Thanks @jimmix, Im not expecting someone will give me the actual code, But all I want is to get some idea or logic to getting started. Anyway! THanks again, It's a big help form me. :D godbless

Comment: @zeus2026 You welcome. See my updated code with comments to get the idea. Also consider [accepting answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you are ok with it.

Comment: hi @jimmix, Thank you, But I've edited my question, please see my edit question. Sorry If I didn't clear up my question.